# Vertx multiple event loops

Tags: vert.x, vertx-verticle

I'm a beginner with Vertx and I'm using [this link](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/#_anatomy_of_a_verticle) as the starter code.

However, there is no main file and I don't see how the MainVerticle is deployed. I would like to set some deployment options for the MainVerticle but since there is no main file; how would I do that?

Comment: see the section: https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/#_bootstrapping_a_maven_project you build a fat-jar with maven and just run the jar with java -jar target/yourApp-fat.jar

Answer (score 0):

The two common ways to do that :

- build a fat jar using the maven shade plugin or exec plugin and the `io.vertx.core.Launcher` class as main class, according to [this documentation](https://vertx.io/docs/guide-for-java-devs/#_bootstrapping_a_maven_project). Then you will be able to run your fat jar with a `java -jar` command.
- My favorite : use the [vertx command line](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_the_vertx_command_line) (like you would do with nodejs for example).

I'd prefer the second solution in order to avoid the duplication of the vert.x core library in your filesystem which can have a real cost when you have to run bunch of vert.x microservices.

Afterwards to go further you can encapsulate that with a resilient services orchestrator like systemd or even docker+kubernetes & co.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this link for you to improve your vert.x knowledge from zero to hero.You will be able to make a crud application using this repository.

https://github.com/saranglohar/vertx-crud-operations-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/com/vertx/student/crud

Answer (score -1):

You can use `main()` very easily:

```java
public class Application {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx()
        vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle());
    }
}
```